# UIActivityView Controller behaviour is strange

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios7, twitter, uiactivityviewcontroller

I need to add share functionality in my app with UIActivityViewController but I have done a lot of research and found that e.g in IOS7 and IOS8 if user has not logined or added account in settings then UIActivityViewController will not load the icons of twitter and Facebook etc. I have seen an app named MusiXMatch they have used the sharing on there songs share module.They are showing Facebook and twitter icons without adding the accounts in settings. I am wondering how this is happening. It seems that it looks likes the default UIActivityViewController but what I have found in my research my UIActivityViewController did not get the icons except login into accounts. This app surprise me a lot. I have to make like this. I have done this think by using OWActivityViewController but it is IOS6 layout. I need to make it as default IOS7 and IOS8. Need solution asap. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own UIActivityType and ask the user to login to the desired app (Facebook, Twitter, etc.) before posting to them but you would need to build the whole activity to handle the communication. You might be able to extract the code from OWAActivityViewController and re-use it.

Comment: I have customised OWAActivitycontroller  a little to look like that some how !